# get content between Custom Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to text between `/*SumitStart*/` To `*SumitStart*/`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var data1 = $("#myid").text();
    // alert(ss);
    var subStr = $("#myid").text().match("/*SumitStart*/(.*)/*SumitEND*/");
    alert(substr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Get Substring</button>
<div id="myid">
  Hello My Div is large /*SumitStart*/ hello chirag good morning welcome /*SumitEND*/ And Now End My DIv sdfsdfsdfs
</div>
```

**My Code** [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/v2hmrjvL/)

Comment: what issue are you experiencing?

Comment: no result are there

Comment: your regex isn't doing what you expect. I would suggest using a site like regexr.com and test to make sure you're capturing the right text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Regular expression

```
var subStr = $("#myid").text().match(/\/\*SumitStart\*\/.*\/\*SumitEND\*\//);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q788a5mz/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var subStr = $("#myid").text().match(/\/\*SumitStart\*\/(.*)\/\*SumitEND\*\//)[0];
// result
/*SumitStart*/ hello chirag good morning welcome /*SumitEND*/

var subStr = $("#myid").text().match(/\/\*SumitStart\*\/(.*)\/\*SumitEND\*\//)[1];
// result
hello chirag good morning welcome
```

Answer (score 1):

This help you :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").on("click",function(){

    $txt = $("div").text();

    $patt = /(\/\*SumitStart\*\/)\s*(.*)\s*(\/\*SumitEND\*\/)/gi;

    $res = $txt.match($patt,"$2");

    alert(RegExp.$2);
   })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    
    <button type="button">Get Substring</button>
    
    <div id="myid">
        Hello My Div is large
       /*SumitStart*/ hello chirag good morning welcome /*SumitEND*/  And Now End My DIv
       sdfsdfsdfs
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").on("click",function(){

            $txt = $("div").text();

            $patt = /(\/\*SumitStart\*\/)\s*(.*)\s*(\/\*SumitEND\*\/)/gi;

            $res = $txt.match($patt,"$2");

            alert(RegExp.$2);
        })
    })
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works :

```
subStr=data1.slice(data1.indexOf("/*SumitStart*/")+"/*SumitStart*/".length,data1.indexOf("/*SumitEND*/"));
```